# Delphi cannot find any database driver

Tags: delphi, odbc, dbase

I'm just trying to connect to database but there's exception:

Project Project.exe raised exception class TDBXError with message 'Unknown driver:  Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)'.

```
uses
  Data.DB, Data.SqlExpr, Vcl.Dialogs;
var
  SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection;
  SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery;
begin
  SQLConnection1 := TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
  SQLQuery1 := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    SQLConnection1.ConnectionName := 'dBase'; // it's my DSN, I called it like this
    SQLConnection1.DriverName := 'Microsoft dBase Driver (.*dbf)'; //and I also tried a lots of drivers
    SQLConnection1.LibraryName := 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcjt32.dll';
    SQLConnection1.Params.Add('Database=C:\DB');
 //here was my username and password
    SQLConnection1.Open;
    SQLQuery1.SQLConnection := SQLConnection1;
    SQLQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT 2-2'; // just nothing
    SQLQuery1.Open;

    while not SQLQuery1.Eof do
    begin

      SQLQuery1.Next;
    end;
  finally
    SQLQuery1.Free;
    SQLConnection1.Close;
    SQLConnection1.Free;
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

[My DSN's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QUUx.png)

I made sure that I'm using 32 bit application, and in the C:\DB files exist.
I also tried to create system DSN and input to SQLConnection1.ConnectionName, but it does not help. Why can't my delhi project see any driver?

Comment: [Delphi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(software)), not [Delhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delhi). Have you made a connection test in the ODBC manager (for settings we're unable to see)?

Comment: [Setting Up TSQLConnection](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Setting_Up_TSQLConnection) , if you want to use a ConnectionName property you need to setup a connection in DataExplorer View . If you want setup connection directly you only need to modify the driver parameter. The DriverName parameter identify the Drivers but they have fixed values like : ASA, ASE, Datasnap, Db2, Firebird, Informix, InterBase, MSSQL, MSSQL9, MySQL, Odbc, and Oracle. It's easyer to test the connection at DesignTime in a Form or Frame before create TSQLConnection runtime.

Comment: [Configuring TSQL Connection](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Configuring_TSQL_Connection) another step by step guide

Comment: connection via forms is working (I entered the 'Odbc' Driver in correct field, but I need to configure connection via console app. Odbc and any other drivers are "not found"